# Symfony2 - something other than bundle

Tags: php, frameworks, symfony

I'm currenly working on the project where i need something orther than bundle. Something i call "Module".
It should be different from the bundle in that when project is starting system doesn't know which "Modules" will be used
and how they will be configured.

Also i'm going to use these modules similar to bundles

```
$response = $this->forward('AcmeHelloModule:Hello:fancy');
```

OR

```
$response = $this->forward('Acme/Hello:Hello:fancy');
```

Here HelloController->fancyAction(); would be executed. And this controller described say in file /src/modules/Acme/Hello/Controller/HelloController.php

So the question is how to implement this ?

Comment: why not use a bundle? the only other thing symfony knows is vendor libraries, but they should not contain controller code.

Comment: "Modules" are needed to create a dynamic CMS, modules will be installed in it for example as it is in Wordpress that is, they will do it with the mouse by the user

Comment: This doesn't explain "why not a bundle"? In fact Symfony2 just calls it's modules "bundle", but they are nothing else than a kind of module. That S2 doesn't provide a solution to include bundles at runtime doesn't mean, that it it's wrong at all (depends on the implementation ;))

Comment: so, there are problems with extending of method forward() and render() ?

Answer (score 0):

In AppKernel add the following method:

```
public function getBundle($name, $first = true)
{
    if (substr($name, -6) == 'Module')) {
        return $this->getBundle('ModuleBundle')->getModule($name, $first);
    }

    return parent::getBundle($name, $first);
}
```

and all the logic runs in ModuleBundle. 
But make sure the type of response is the same as Kernel->getBundle();

Answer (score 0):

a solution would be to implement a PluginBundle that can dynamicly install, load and run your so called modules.

the PluginBundle would not contain specific plugin code at all, but the runtime environment for you modules/plugins. you may then save in the database which plugins/modules are enabled and load them dynamicly at runtime.

with this sollution it should be possible to create a dynamic plugin mechanism as in wordpress. modifying the AppKernel at runtime is not a good solution because you'd also have to clear the cache when en- disabeling bundles.